# Javadoc for enum field method

Tags: enums, javadoc

I have an enum which implements an interface. The method is implemented in its constants with a comment for each method:

```
public interface MyIF{
    int foo1();
}

public enum SomeTypes implements MyIF{
    TYPE_ONE {
        /**
          * this method ...
          *
          * @return ...
          */
        @Override
        public int foo1() {...}
    }, ...
}
```

Javadoc ignores the method comment. Everything else is generated fine. Is there a way I can make these comments appear in the generated javadoc ?
Thanks

Comment: This is not supported by Javadoc, as documented [in this JDK bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6287562). According to the comments on the bug, Oracle does not intend to support this (the bug is also marked as `won't-fix`).